# Unknown error in PHP when using Google Cloud Vision Service

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

enter image description herei'm getting this error and i don't know how to debug this.

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Google\ApiCore\Middleware\RetryMiddleware::Google\ApiCore\Middleware{closure}() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given, called in /Users/../Desktop/VISION MAIN/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php on line 203 and defined in /Users/../Desktop/VISION MAIN/vendor/google/gax/src/ApiCore/Middleware/RetryMiddleware.php:90
>   Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /Users/../Desktop/VISION MAIN/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(203): Google\ApiCore\Middleware\RetryMiddleware->Google\ApiCore\Middleware{closure}(Object(Error))
>
> ## 1 /Users/../Desktop/VISION MAIN/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(156): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(2, Object(Error), Array)
>
> ## 2 /Users/../Desktop/VISION MAIN/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/TaskQueue.php(47): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise{closure}()
>
> ## 3 /Users/../Desktop/VISION MAIN/vendor/guzzleh in /Users/../Desktop/VISION MAIN/vendor/google/gax/src/ApiCore/Middleware/RetryMiddleware.php on line 90

[Request in php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVLuE.png)

[main.php(call the request php file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OQ2p.png)

[swift code call the main.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91JbA.png)

Comment: Please share the code you're using which triggers this error. Be sure to redact sensitive data such as your project ID and keyfile.

Comment: Check the [official documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/gax-php/0.37.0/Google/ApiCore/Middleware/RetryMiddleware.html) to know what input is the method expecting. This issue could also be related to "bcmath" extension lack, as described [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/issues/950#issuecomment-377948496)